# Turning snake scale object into seamless texture and displacement map?

Tags: uv, displacement

How would you turn this snake scale object with *Array* modifier into usable seamless texture in order to unwrap a snake model.

[image]

[image]

Made it work, with one more hiccup of "bald" spots:

1. Create the scale object with Array modifier, then render a displacement map image in EXR.
2. Then, make a material with the Image Texture node and Displacement node.
3. Then Append the material into the actual snake body object.

Comment: you could bake the normal of the first object and project it on the surface of your second object? Choose Unwrap > Cylinder Projection or Follow Active Quads

Comment: Not really sure how to go about baking the normals... Is there a link you could provide?

Comment: maybe check this tuto? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kg0wIBIpGG0

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arvhK4tvYuY&t=104s&ab_channel=DefaultCube Made it work with this really clever video.

Comment: baking the normals is much easier imho